# Fault on a tri-phasic circuit

Tags: power-engineering, fault

I work on a industry as an intern and I'm having a trouble. Clearly there's a fault on the net, but I can't figure out which type it is since I'm having strange readings from a basic multimeter. I'm in Minas Gerais, on Brazil, where each phase have 127 V and here it's a very common practice the neutral grounded (there's no difference between the ground and neutral). So, let's go on.

When I measure each live to neutral it gives me 127 V, also does ground to neutral.

When I measure each live to ground:

A to GND: 220 V

B to GND: 0 V

C to GND: 220 V

Neutral to GND: 127 V

If we change the reference a possible voltage on conductors are as follows:

A: 127 /-120°

B: 127 /0°

C: 127 /120°

Neutral: 0

GND: 127 /0°

Anyone have an idea of what's my problem? What's the simplest/cheapest way to solve it?

Thx very much

Comment: The electrical installment is roughly projected and done. Also we do not have a plant and possible the circuit breakers are badly dimensioned.

Comment: It seems like B and Neutral are flipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship between phase voltage and line voltage (difference between two phase voltages) is \$\sqrt3\$ = 1.732. If you multiply 127 by 1.732 you get 219.9 volts. This should reliably tell you that line B is grounded instead of neutral.

Comment: but if B is grounded the voltage between B and another live will be 127 and not 220, right?

Comment: No, it will be 1.732 x 127V = 220V

Comment: Can you explain me why? Since 220 V comes from the sum of two waves of 127 V with 120° of difference (if there is no difference it will be 254 V, and if it was 180° it will be 0 V). But if we change one of 127 V by ground (0 volt) the sum will be 127 V and not 220 V. Where is my mistake?

Comment: 3-phase theory: if phase voltage is X then line voltage will be 1.732 times higher and not twice as high. Look it up and you'll see I'm completely correct.

Comment: http://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/tech/wyedelta.gif and see this: http://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/tech/threeph.htm

Comment: Yeah, but again only if we have 127 on each phase. This comes from sum of sinusoids which for 120° of difference between phases give us the √3 ratio. I think it stills does not explain why I'm measuring 220 V between A to GND and C to GND. How can GND can be another phase? And if so, I'll suppose to measure 220 V also between the Neutral and GND (since B and Neutral are flipped). Sorry for annoying, but I'm still not getting the point and will not try a procedure if I'm not 100% right.

Comment: The 3 ph you are measuring probably comes from an isolation transformer so grounding one of the phase voltages (by mistake) is not going to be self-revealing. You measured 0v between B and ground - doesn't this tell you that the B output is likely shorted to gnd?

Comment: Sure it does. It was my first thought when I measured the voltages, but then started to think on other measurements and then I get uncertain of it. All my doubts are related to the points I showed you. Thx very much, I'll try to invert the B and neutral when the industry stop.

Comment: We solved it. Probably the connection of neutral to ground it's not very fine. We had just to reground the neutral

Comment: @PedroQuadros - that doesn't really explain your measurements unless you had some load connected between B and earth and nothing on the other phases.

Comment: we thought it has been solved. It doesn't worked =/.

Comment: @PedroQuadros - I didn't think it would - you have a "rogue" connection between B and earth as I said yesterday.